# How to determine if the string is subdomain or not C#

Tags: c#

I have list of domains in a richtext control, and wanna determine if the domain is subdomain or not, and if its subdomain, wanna get top level domain, I already know how to get the top level , but it return with subdomain as top level domain

Example: 
wiki.google.com/wiki/

this reutrn wiki.google.com as top level domain,

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean. If you have `wiki.google.com/wiki` you could split the string by `/`, taking everything before that as your domain. Then split whatever is left by `.` The last segment (.com) is the top-level. The next-to-last is a domain, and every preceding one is a subdomain.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking (in addition to not *showing* what you already now) - Top-Level-Domain (TLD) for "wiki.google.com" is ".com"  - so both "wiki.google.com" and "google.com" can be called "subdomains"... Some explicit example could help.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "[Regular Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2)" for example in this case

```
        var str = "wiki.google.com/wiki/";
        var reg = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(.+\..+\..+)/.+");
        string domain = null;
        if (reg.IsMatch(str))
            domain = reg.Matches(str)[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Likely bad suggestion (unless OP actually starts with random text)  - there is `Uri` and `UriBuilder` classes to deal with this particular cases to at least extract host nam... Plus you did not explain what OP mean "subdomain" - technically `google.com` has `google` as second level and `.com` as top level which clearly does not align with OP's remarks... but what about "chat.physics.stackexchange.com" - is it "subdomain" and if it is what is "main domain"?

Comment: Assuming OP means a subdomain of a regular purchased domain, your logic only works if the purchased domain is a second-level domain. If it's a third-level domain (e.g. https://bbc.co.uk) then your code detects bbc.co.uk as a subdomain of .co.uk (probably not what OP wanted).